# An empty array shows up non-empty when returned from function

Tags: html, angularjs

I'm trying to push some items into an array but for simplicity sake I'm using the following code as an example. `filterObj` is an empty object but when pushed onto array `filterArr`, filterArr contains `[{}]`. I tried to put in a if condition:

```
if(filterObj != {}) {
    $scope.filterArr.push(filterObj);
}
```

The above `if` condition doesn't work because the output still turns out to be `[{}]`

Code :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html  ng-app>
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.13/angular.js"></script>
<script type='text/javascript'>
function MyCtrl($scope) {
    $scope.lines = [];

    $scope.filterArr = [];
    var filterObj = new Object();
    filterObj = {};
    $scope.filterArr.push(filterObj);

    $scope.addLine = function () {
        $scope.lines.push($scope.lines.length);
    };
}
</script>
</head>
<body>
  <div ng-app ng-controller="MyCtrl">
    <button ng-click="addLine()">Run</button>
    <div ng-repeat="line in lines">
        FilterArr : {{filterArr}}.
    </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

What I would like to see is that when `filterArr` is output, it should show `[]` instead of `[{}]`
Thanks for your help!

Comment: Try a simple `{} == {}`, it's always `false`.

Comment: Yes it does work. But the problem is that I need to check on `filterObj`. If `filterObj` is empty then I would need the output `filterArr` as `[]`

Comment: Well this is solved. The other question helped. My bad I didn't get to that question while searching. Thanks @deceze